# Display dates in a list, not select option

Tags: javascript, date

I have a function that displays today's current date along with the next 60 days however I am not sure how to convert this so that it displays in a normal list, as opposed to a select element.

```
var dateRange = document.getElementById('date-range'),
    monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

for(var day = 0; day < 60; day++) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);
  dateRange.options[dateRange.options.length] = new Option([date.getDate(), monthNames[date.getMonth()], date.getFullYear()].join(' '), date.toISOString());
}
```

```
<select id="date-range">
</div>
```

Comment: "this so that it displays in a normal list, as opposed to a select element." I can't get the question, can you please clarify it?

Comment: At the moment, the dates are shown in a drop down element as the select element has been used. I'm trying to change it so that the days are just populated as a list. I've tried changing the element to a normal <ul> element but I get an error that 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined....'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var dateRange = document.getElementById('date-range');
    monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

for(var day = 0; day < 60; day++) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);
  
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  
  
  var MyDateString = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/'
             + monthNames[date.getMonth()] // +   '/'
          //   + date.getFullYear();
  
  
  
  
  li.innerHTML = MyDateString;
  dateRange.appendChild(li);
  
}
```

```html
<ul id="date-range">
</ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you! However it displays the full date along with the time. Is there any way just for the day and month to be shown?

Comment: see updated answer. Please accept if this works for you.